# Section id a few lines up

Tags: html

I'm using links like:

```
<a href="#id">
```

to go to the `<section id="id">`. But on my webpage, there's a "sticky header", so the menu follows when you scroll. So if I set the section id a place, this place is actually hidden behind the header. Is there anyway to say the section id should be few lines before this place?

Comment: Add some padding/margin

Comment: Add margin-top to the section exactly as the height of the header

Answer (score 0):

With such little code provide this is what I can say:

- add Spacer control  with height equal to menu height into each Section
- use anchor moved a little top. For example, an empty link with ID
  which moved with absolute positioning a little top from Section.

Hope this helps